# empty function for required fields

Tags: php, string

Good evening!

I´ve been trying hard to solve this issue by myself but I couldn´t. I know problably that is something simple but I couldn´t find it. The script works, however when it stars it shows some issues you ignore them and introduce the data and it works perfectly. I think I need a if clause but I don´t know how tho apply. I´m new in this and I really appreciate your help. Many thanks!

This is the problem:

```
Undefined index : busca in ...
Undefined variable busqueda 
Faltal error call to a member function fetch array on a non object in ....
```

I think when the page opens the codes runs empty, without data, that´s why I receive those messages. Thanks for your help

```
<head>
<title>SISTEMA DE REGISTRO DE PRODUCTOS CTE</title>
<style type="text/css">
#enviar {
    text-align: right;
}
.letrasbody {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
.letra {
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php

session_start();

require "conexiondb.php";
 ?>
<form name="busquedas" method="POST" action="busqueda.php">
  <table width="1142" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#0033FF" scope="col"><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="letrasbody">SISTEMA DE CONTRO Y REGISTRO DE PRODUCTOS Y SERVICIOS</p>
        <p class="letrasbody">CTE </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="491" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="641">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="letra"><p>Numero de orden o </p>
      <p>numero de cedula</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="busca" id="busca"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="buscar" value="Buscar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


<?php
$busca = $_POST['busca'];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (!empty ($_POST['busca'])){
        echo "Indique su busqueda";
    }
}
if ($busca!=""){ 
    $busqueda=$con->query("SELECT * FROM clientes C INNER JOIN producto P ON C.serial  = P.serial WHERE P.serial  like '%".$busca."%' or c.cedula like '%".$busca."%' " );

}

echo "<table border=1> 
    <tr>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Orden numero</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Barrio</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Producto</th>
    <th>Marca</th>
    <th>Almacen</th>
    <th>Dano</th>
    <th>Fecha de recepcion</th>
    <th>Tecnico</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Sede</th>
    <th>Fecha de entrega</th>
    </tr>";

$rowColors = Array('#A6A6FF','#FFFFFF'); $nRow = 0;
while ($muestra=$busqueda->fetch_array()){
    echo '<tr style="background-color:'.$rowColors[$nRow++ % count($rowColors)].';">';

    echo '<td>' .$muestra['cliente'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['cedula']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['serial']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['email']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['barrio'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['telefono']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['producto']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['marca']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['almacen']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['dano'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['fecharecepcion']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['tecnico']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['estado']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['sede']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$muestra['entregaacliente']. '</td>';


}

mysqli_close ($con)

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the *issues* are what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing your code for when a `POST` request is made and when possibly no `POST` request is made, through the whole page.

For example: If no `POST` request is made, `$_POST['busca']` is undefined but you put that line before you check for the `POST` request. The same for `$busqueda`; that variable is only defined when a `POST` request is made, but when you use it, you don't check for that.

You should cleanly separate the code for when a `POST` request is made and when not. You could also initialize your variables and check for the initialization values at the times when you use them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i really appreaciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you page first loads, no data is posted to the page. you can add this check before trying to do anything with the data.

```
<?php
if (isset( $_POST['busca']) // if the data is posted
{
//all your code here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i knew it was the problem but i didn´t know how to fix it. I know this script is plenty of mistakes but at least it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have LOTS of problems in your code.

You have to put `session_start()` before you produce any output. It should be at the very start of the file.

You assign `$busca = $_POST['busca'];` before checking `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`. So you're doing this assignment when you're displaying the form, not just when the user submits it. But `$_POST['busca']` isn't set that time, so you get a warning about `Undefined index 'busca'`.

This test is backwards:

```
if (!empty ($_POST['busca'])){
    echo "Indique su busqueda";
}
```

You're displaying the error when the field is not empty, but you should display it when it *is* empty, right?

You only perform the query and assign `$busqueda` when `$busca` is set. But later you have the loop:

```
while ($muestra=$busqueda->fetch_array()){
```

even though `$busqueda` isn't set. That's why you get the `Undefined variable $busqueda` error and the error about calling `fetch_array` on a non-object (because `$busqueda` is undefined).

You need to review all the logic of your script, and make sure it only does the parts that are used to process a form when the form input has been given. Otherwise it should just display the empty form.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ill will keep all them in mind to improve the script.Regards!